# How to search on a varchar column using a number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a varchar(30) column that looks like this:

```
953-41
975-12
952-13
934-34
```

All numbers of the column share the structure of: 3 numbers and a dash followed by more numbers.

I want to make a query that works like `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value = 95341` 

And get '953-41' only using numbers in the WHERE clause.

I can't change my database and remove the dash, I need to search with a numeric value on rows that mix the numbers I want with a dash in between.

Comment: can you explain your use case a little more? *Why* do you need to use `95341` rather than `"953-41"` to search?

Comment: It's related to phone numbers, and this is the best method i can use for my project for sure. I've considered other options but they're more complex and I want to keep it simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try:

MYSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value = INSERT(95341,4,0,'-')
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value = STUFF(95341,4,0,'-')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(colName, '-', '') AS UNSIGNED) = 95341
```